# Checkbox conditional class in Angular is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

In this simple example, I am trying to add a class to `checkbox input` if it is checked. I don't know why this simple example is not working. Can someone help me out?

```
<html>
<head> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
</head> 
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked" ng-class="{peter: isChecked}" />
    <script>
        //Module Declaration
        var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        //Controller Declaration
        app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
            //No code
        });
    </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: I have added the rest of code.

Comment: I tried this out in a fiddle and it seems to work correctly to me.

Adds the class 'peter' to the checkbox element when it is checked.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3symw9f0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide more code. <strike>I'll delete this answer if this is a typo but you are missing `/>` in the `input field.</strike>

<strike>Change `<input type="checkbox" ng-class="{peter: isChecked}"` to `<input type="checkbox" ng-class="{peter: isChecked}" />`.</strike>

Just change your line

```
app.controller = ('myCtrl',function($scope){
    //No code
});
```

to

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    //No code
});
```

Your controller was declared with the wrong syntax. There is dev console in every browser. You should fire it and first see the errors :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your controller wasn't declared correctly.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  //No code
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  //No code
});
```

This is right code for controller.

Answer (score 2):

Your example works fine. When the checkbox is checked, i can see that:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-class="{peter: isChecked}" ng-model="isChecked" class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse peter">
```